# Attaching multiple values to a single div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mapbox

I am using the following mapbox.js [example](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/non-exclusive-markers/) to filter features from a geojson file.  The example is self-explanatory - the first step is to find all checkboxes that are checked and to build a list of their values.

At the moment, the checkbox values are all single strings.  My question is simple, can `value` in the checkboxes be an array of integers (or an array of strings?), and if so, how would attach an array of integers to `value` in a `div input` so that you can filter by multiple values at once?

```
for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
        if (checkboxes[i].checked) on.push(checkboxes[i].value);

<div id='filters' class='ui-select'>
  <div><input type='checkbox' checked=checked class='filter'
             name='filter' id='fast-food' value='fast-food'/><label for='fast-food'>fast-food</label></div>
  <div><input type='checkbox' checked=checked class='filter'
             name='filter' id='bicycle' value='bicycle'/><label for='bicycle'>bicycle</label></div>
  <div><input type='checkbox' checked=checked class='filter'
             name='filter' id='bar' value='bar'/><label for='bar'>bar</label></div>
</div>
<div id='map'></div>

<script>
L.mapbox.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoiaXNrYW5kYXJibHVlIiwiYSI6ImNpazE3MTJldjAzYzZ1Nm0wdXZnMGU2MGMifQ.i3E1_b9QXJS8xXuPy3OTcg';
var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'mapbox.dc-markers');
var filters = document.getElementById('filters');
var checkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName('filter');

function change() {
    // Find all checkboxes that are checked and build a list of their values
    var on = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
        if (checkboxes[i].checked) on.push(checkboxes[i].value);
    }
    // The filter function takes a GeoJSON feature object
    // and returns true to show it or false to hide it.
    map.featureLayer.setFilter(function (f) {
        // check each marker's symbol to see if its value is in the list
        // of symbols that should be on, stored in the 'on' array
        return on.indexOf(f.properties['marker-symbol']) !== -1;
    });
    return false;
}

// When the form is touched, re-filter markers
filters.onchange = change;
// Initially filter the markers
change();
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take advantage of jQuery's [.data() method](https://api.jquery.com/data/) which allows you to assign a property name and value to an element on the DOM. You could set the data element's value to a comma-delimited list of integers which can be parsed into its own array.

Some (untested) pseudocode as an example:

```
<div id='filters' class='ui-select'>
  <div><input type='checkbox' checked=checked class='filter'
             name='filter' id='fast-food' value='fast-food' data-filter='fast-food,restaurants'/><label for='fast-food'>fast-food</label></div>
  <div><input type='checkbox' checked=checked class='filter'
             name='filter' id='bicycle' value='bicycle'/><label for='bicycle' data-filter='bicycle, transportation'>bicycle</label></div>
  <div><input type='checkbox' checked=checked class='filter'
             name='filter' id='bar' value='bar' data-filter='bar, restaurants'/><label for='bar'>bar</label></div>
</div>

...

function change() {
    // Find all checkboxes that are checked and build a list of their values
    var on = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
        if (checkboxes[i].checked) {
          var array = $(checkboxes[i]).data("filter").split(',');
          Array.prototype.push.apply(on,array);
        }
    }

    ...
}
```